# Which hook do I need to use to pull external content in pages?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I want some of my pages to pull content from another application. Someone suggest I should [write a module to do that](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/57300/12811).
As I'm a complete beginner in Drupal I was wondering which [hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7) do I need to implement (a snippet would be greatly appreciated) :

- hook_page_alter
- hook_page_delivery_callback_alter
- something else ?

Comment: do you just want to add the content to your page or save it as a node in drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) is used to alter the page returned from another module, and [hook_page_delivery_callback_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_delivery_callback_alter/7) is used to change the page delivery callback for a page output from another module. All the hooks with a name ending with _alter are hooks that alter the output of another module, what another module returns, or the data stored by another module.

The hook you should use is [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to define a page callback, and [drupal_http_request()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) to get the external content.
The minimal code you should use is similar to the following one.

```
  function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_external_content_view',
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

    return $items;
  }

function mymodule_external_content_view() {
  $response = drupal_http_request($url);
  if (!isset($response->error)) {
    $data = $response->data;

    return array(
      '#markup' => filter_xss($response->data, $allowed_tags)
    );
  }
}
```

Replace abc/def with the path of the page you want to output, `$url` with the URL of the external application, and `$allowed_tags` with an array of strings for the tags that you want to allow as output. By default, [filter_xss()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss/7) uses `array('a', 'em', 'strong', 'cite', 'code', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'dl', 'dt', 'dd')`.

Comment: Do I need to have the `abc/def` page ? I would prefer to have only a menu entry as the page will be empty.

Comment: The path can be the one you prefer, not necessarily one containing a slash.

Comment: Here is what I've done so far and which work (expect some bad URLs) : http://pastebin.com/UZhkMpjr